# Fetch while data using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, while-loop

I want table data like this but fetching data dynamically using `while` or `for` loop.

```
<table border =  1 width = "1200px"  style="background-color:#FFCE4B;">
<tr>
    <th class = "font-heading-currency">County</th>
    <th class = "font-heading-currency">CCode</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <span class = "ctryname">USA</span>
        <span class = "ctryname">Euro</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="back">USD</span>
        <span class="front">EUR</span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <span class = "ctryname">United Kingdom</span>
        <span class = "ctryname">Australia</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="back">UK</span>
        <span class="front">AUD</span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <span class = "ctryname">Japan</span>
        <span class = "ctryname">Canada</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="back">JPY</span>
        <span class="front">CAD</span>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is my table data:

```
County          | CCode
--------------- | ------
USA             | USD
Euro            | EUR
United Kingdom  | UK
Australia       | AUD
Japan           | JPY
Canada          | CAD
```

How can I fetch the data dynamically using `while` or `for` loop.
Can anyone help for this?

Comment: where is your code

Comment: you have to read php and mysqli and try if you getting any error we can help you.but without any code we can't able to help you.

Comment: Please don't use mysql anymore! if you must, use mysqli. PDO is also a good option.

Answer (score 0):

**PLEASE DO NOT USE MYSQL, USE MYSQLI OR PDO PREPARED STATEMENTS!**

Here is a mysqli solution that will work for you.

```
$result = $MySQLi->query($sqlStr);
$data = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

echo $data;
echo $data["fieldname"];
```